# Have data query automatically refresh if other query is refresehed first

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two data queries. I want to have the 2nd query automatically refreshed if the first query is manually refreshed. Below is the VBA code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Query2").QueryTable.Refresh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem with the above code is that it tries to refresh the 2nd query before the first is finished which causes an error. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: *"which causes an error"* - what error?

Comment: Run-time error 1004: "Microsoft Excel is refreshing some data. Please try again later" .

Answer (score 1):

By default the Power Query tables does a background refresh meaning it will take some time before it finishes the loading depending on the size of data. The trick here is to disable the background refresh which tell your macro to finish the refresh before executing another task.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Query2").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```